# How to make Htmlunit Session alive

Tags: session, htmlunit

I use htmlunit wrote a demo that order to get data from a website，but After a period of time，I can't get any data anymore，I guess it's because session timeout，so i want to ask:"how can i keep the session alive".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit tries to simulate real browsers - think about HtmlUnit as an browser you can control with you program instead a real browser is controlled by a person.

Next stop: try to understand what is going on and what is your real problem. Figure out if there is some kind of session timeout if you use a real browser with the website. Use web proxies like Charles or Fiddler to understand what is going on on the wire. A session is usually based on cookies and always controlled from the server.

Next one: Think about how the user (with the browser) will keep the session alive. Maybe there are regular actions from the user side triggering some server events refreshing the session. Or some kind of regular javascript action doing the magic.

And finally: if you know what is going on you can simulate the same with HtmlUnit.

Hope that helps.